# Average human force and torque wrench length

Tags: torque, wrench

I'm going to buy a torque wrench for some high-torque bolts in my car. I need a torque wrench to torque bolts from 130 nm (95.8 lb-ft) to 160 nm (118 lb-ft). I found some torque wrenches which support a range of 30 - 210 nm. However, I found a problem with all of them and that is the length of wrench. All torque wrenches of this range (even the most expensive ones) are about half a meter long (20 inches).
Now, imagine you want to torque a particular bolt in your car to 160 nm (118 lb-ft).
Torque = Force x Distance >
160 nm (16.31 kg/m) = Force x 0.50 (meter) >
**Force** = 16.31 / 0.5 = **32.6 kg (about 72 pounds)**

**Do you think an average human arm can exert such a force (72 pounds) to a torque wrench handle?**
Why don't they make torque wrenches a bit longer?
I don't think adding an extension to the wrench would be a good idea because you may damage it.

Comment: We used to clamp a torque wrench into a bench vice set to 100lb/ft, then the challenge was to “click” it WITHOUT any method of bracing yourself against the bench. So 1 arm to pull and both feet on the floor - no other contact. It was fun taking the piss out of the feeble ones :)

Comment: And they do make longer torque wrenches : like 2m long - used on trucks etc.

Comment: @Solar Mike - How much force you could exert by your arm without any assistance? Can you give me an estimate?

Comment: I gave you exactly that. Did you not read my first comment? What did you not understand?

Comment: @Solar Mike - In your first comment, you only mentioned 100 lb-ft. I don't know the length of your torque wrench to calculate kg or pounds.

Comment: So 100lb/ft is the setting on the torque wrench - it does not matter how long that particular one was. That is why we use them so the applied torque is the same whether you have a small torque wrench and a large person or a long torque wrench and a small person. The APPLIED torque on the fastener will be the same.

Comment: @Solar Mike - I think you didn't understand my question. I know the torque will be the same no matter how short or long your wrench is. Here, I want to know the mass your arm could exert to the wrench not the torque you applied! The power of your arm is what I need to know. Even a weak person can apply 1000 nm of torque with a long handle but he will never be able to apply the same torque with  a 20 cm handle!

Comment: Just go to a mechanic who is large and strong.

Comment: My guess is you've never changed a flat tire because a 4-way lug wrench will allow an average man to use both hands to generate as much as 120 ft lbs. These are typical 4-way lug wrenches spanning close to three feet from one end to the other. I can easily generate approximately 85 ft lbs (checked against a torque wrench) with a lug wrench. I've recently rebuilt a1.5 ton floor jack but needed a very long 2x6 as resistance against a pipe wrench with an iron black pipe extension to loosen the very tight cap screw. I'm guessing well over 150 ft lbs but who cares as long as leverage is used.

Comment: @F Dryer - Your guess about flat tire is right but if you think I have never removed a wheel from my car, you are wrong (I have done it many times for replacing belts or other services). I have also tested my 4-way lug wrench many times and noticed that I can generate about 110 - 120 nm (not lb-ft) easily with my both hands. I even used a hanging scale to measure how many kilos I had applied to the wrench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a torque wrench of the same dimensions that you are talking about and can operate it without a problem.

While I can pick up a weights a lot heavier than 72lb (32kg), you will find that operating a torque wrench on the higher settings is not just about using your arm.  You will likely hold it with both hands and use your whole body to move the wrench to give a smooth action to the movement.  It may be that you keep your arms straight and use your legs to move you or you lean to pull on the wrench, but it will rarely be just your arm doing the work.

Comment: I already have a smaller torque wrench (0.38 meter long and 15 - 80 nm range). I can easily apply 80 nm with it which equals 21 kg of force. Since I'm not a muscular man like you, I wanted to make sure if I can manage 32 kg of force or not!

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian 32kg is not a force - it is a mass. Do keep track of your units…

Comment: @Solar Mike - I know it is a mass but here I'm referring to it as a force for easier explanation.

Comment: @Nso 32kg applied at 0.5m, 1m or 2m? That is why we use the correct units.